# Error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib' PyISAPIe

Tags: wsgi, pyisapie

Am trying to compile a 64bit version of PyISAPIe using VS2010. Am not used to C/C++ programming but managed to configure some settings for VS2010. Everything went well until it got to the linking stage where it gave the above mentioned error. I checked all the Library path settings and they looked fine. Below is my command line for building the DLL:

`/OUT:"x64\Release\PyISAPIe.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\pyisapie\Python\x64\Python27\libs" /LIBPATH:"C:\pyisapie\Python\x64\Python26\libs" /LIBPATH:"C:\pyisapie\Python\x64\Python25\libs" /DLL "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"libc libcmt msvcrt" /DEF:"PyISAPIe.def" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\PyISAPIe.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /PDB:"C:\pyisapie\x64\Release\PyISAPIe.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PGD:"C:\pyisapie\x64\Release\PyISAPIe.pgd" /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE:NO /IMPLIB:"x64\Release\PyISAPIe.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE`

The path **C:\pyisapie\Python\x64\Python27\libs** exists and containes python27.lib.

Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just compared your linker command line to mine (I'm the project author) and it's exactly the same as far as flags go, so you might want to look into other reasons why the file can't be opened. Is it an x64 lib for sure? Do you have access?

You might try reinstalling the newest 2.7 x64 release into a different location and add that folder instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue due to not setting the LIBPATH correctly. This may not be the cause of your error message, but it was the cause of mine.

To resolve it in Visual Studio right click on the PyISAPIe project and select: 
**Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > General**

Then make sure that the path `C:\pyisapie\Python\x64\Python27\libs` (or the relative path) is listed in the "Additional Library Directories"